# Missing header in qt 5.2.1

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a Qt newbie. I'm trying to run tutorial from http://doc.qt.digia.com/3.3/tictac-example.html. However, I got error:

> qptrvector.h: No such file or directory".

I have no idea what's going on. Anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: That's a Qt 3.3 tutorial, which definitely won't work with Qt 5.2.  Here's a more recent example: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtdesigner-taskmenuextension-example.html (though I don't know if it's exactly equivalent to the 3.3 tutorial).

Comment: @RA Yes. But I still want to test the old example. Is there a way to do that with my QT 5.2.1 creator?

Comment: @user3081703: install Qt 3.3 if you can get it from somewhere, but there is no guarantee it will work. Why would you like to do that anyway?

Comment: @user3081703 It could take quite a bit of time to get this example to work.  For `QPtrVector` specifically, you'll need to replace it with `QVector`.  See also: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/porting4.html

Comment: @LaszloPapp I went through the old example and I think that's closer to what I'm going to build. I guess there should not be too much of a difference. I can try a couple of changes and switch qptrvector to qvector.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a very old example which was written ~10 years ago. As the technology evolves, this is not up-to-date anymore, and you should **not** look at it even if you could manage to run it. It will confuse you more than help.

For instance, there is no `QPtrVector` anymore, but that is just one of those examples. Even if you take a look at a later example, you will find QtQuick1 (old and "done/obsolete") demonstration for the tictac example.

I think you wish to take a look at the examples from these years, e.g. `QtQuickControls`:

[Qt Quick Controls Examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-examples.html)

or this one:

[Task Menu Extension Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtdesigner-taskmenuextension-example.html)